# Very Slow MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, performance, performance-tuning

I'm working with a web app running on MySQL. It uses stored procedures for all database-related tasks. The original web app and the database were designed by another developer; I'm only maintaining it (I'm not a database admin, only a developer). While checking website performance, I found two stored procedures which take almost 20s to execute. That's too much time. But I don't understand how I can optimize this.

I tried to check if indexes are being used, but no luck as the explain does not work with stored procedures. Any help to start working on optimizing these will be highly appreciated. I have tried many suggestions based on other questions like use truncate instead of creating new table, etc. But no significant performance increase so far (almost the same).

[MySQL: how to optimize the stored procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/mysql-how-to-optimize-the-stored-procedure)
[How to know what to investigate and how for a VERY slow stored procedure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24787/how-to-know-what-to-investigate-and-how-for-a-very-slow-stored-procedure)

Here is my server info:
[image]

Here is a screenshot of my slow query log related to this stored procedure:
[image]

Here is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `get_latest`(_user_id int, topic_id int, offset int, row_count int)
BEGIN

    DECLARE record_count INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _level_id INT DEFAULT 3;

    DECLARE _found_records INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE _records_to_fetch INT DEFAULT 0;

    SET NAMES utf8;
    SET CHARACTER SET utf8;
    SET character_set_connection = utf8;
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 100000;

    -- create a temp table to hold all the child topics
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS topic_ids;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE topic_ids (topic_id INT);

    SET _level_id = (SELECT user_topic.level_id FROM user_topic WHERE user_topic.user_id = _user_id AND user_topic.topic_id = topic_id);
    IF _level_id IS NULL THEN SET _level_id = 3; END IF;

    IF topic_id = 0 THEN

        -- insert all the subscribed topics - only the top level topics the user has subscribed to
        INSERT INTO topic_ids
        (SELECT user_topic.topic_id FROM user_topic WHERE user_topic.user_id = _user_id);

        SELECT 
            resource.resource_id
            ,resource.title
            ,topic.display_name AS 'topic'
            ,resource.topic_id
            ,topic.path_ids
            ,resource.link AS 'url'
            ,resource.sponsored
            ,(SELECT CONCAT(
                "[",
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CONCAT("{first_name:'",user.first_name,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",last_name:'",user.last_name,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",thumbnail_image:'",user.thumbnail_image,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",my_comment:",CASE WHEN user.user_id = _user_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
                    ,CONCAT(",comment_id:'",user_comment.comment_id,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",comment:'",user_comment.comments,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",added_date:'",DATE_FORMAT(user_comment.added_date, '%a, %d %b, %Y %H:%i:%S'),"'")
                    ,"}"
                ),
                "]"
            ) FROM user_comment INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = user_comment.user_id WHERE user_comment.resource_id = resource.resource_id) AS comments
            ,resource.like_count
            ,0 AS 'commentCount'
            ,resource.details AS 'detail'
            ,CASE 
                WHEN resource.preview_image IS NULL OR resource.is_duplicate_privew_img = 1 THEN ''
                ELSE resource.preview_image
            END AS preview_image
            ,resource.preview_img_width
            ,user_topic_follow(_user_id,resource.submitted_by,topic_id) AS 'follows'
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE resource.submitted_by 
            END AS submitted_by
            ,CASE
                 WHEN resource.submitted_by = _user_id THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
            END AS 'submitted_by_me'
            ,resource.resource_id
            ,'' AS 'likeCls'
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.date_added IS NULL THEN ''
                ELSE  DATE_FORMAT(resource.date_added, '%a, %d %b, %Y %H:%i:%S') 
                END AS 'date_added'
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN null
                ELSE user.thumbnail_image 
                END AS user_thumb
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN 'Anonymous'
                ELSE concat(user.first_name,' ', user.last_name)  
                END AS 'full_name'             
            ,20 AS probability 
            ,0 AS likesCount
            ,0 AS sharesCount
        FROM
            resource
            INNER JOIN topic_ids ON topic_ids.topic_id = resource.topic_id
            LEFT JOIN user_rating ON user_rating.resource_id = resource.resource_id AND user_rating.user_id = _user_id
            INNER JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id = resource.topic_id
            INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = resource.submitted_by
        WHERE
            (user_rating.rating IS NULL) OR NOT (user_rating.rating = -2 OR user_rating.rating = -1 OR user_rating.rating = 2)
        ORDER BY 
            resource.date_added DESC
        LIMIT 
           offset, row_count;

    ELSE 

        -- insert the topic id to the table
        INSERT INTO topic_ids
        VALUES
        (topic_id);

        -- insert all it's children
        INSERT INTO topic_ids
        (SELECT topic_children.topic_id FROM topic_children WHERE topic_children.parent_id = topic_id);

        SELECT 
            resource.resource_id
            ,resource.title
            ,topic.display_name AS 'topic'
            ,resource.topic_id
            ,resource.like_count
            ,topic.path_ids
            ,resource.link AS 'url'
            ,resource.sponsored
            ,(SELECT CONCAT(
                "[",
                GROUP_CONCAT(
                    CONCAT("{first_name:'",user.first_name,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",last_name:'",user.last_name,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",thumbnail_image:'",user.thumbnail_image,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",my_comment:",CASE WHEN user.user_id = _user_id THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
                    ,CONCAT(",comment_id:'",user_comment.comment_id,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",comment:'",user_comment.comments,"'")
                    ,CONCAT(",added_date:'",DATE_FORMAT(user_comment.added_date, '%a, %d %b, %Y %H:%i:%S'),"'")
                    ,"}"
                ),
                "]"
            ) FROM user_comment INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = user_comment.user_id WHERE user_comment.resource_id = resource.resource_id) AS comments
            ,0 AS 'commentCount'
            ,resource.details AS 'detail'
            ,CASE 
                WHEN resource.preview_image IS NULL OR resource.is_duplicate_privew_img = 1 THEN ''
                ELSE resource.preview_image
            END AS preview_image
            ,resource.preview_img_width
            /*,user_topic_follow(_user_id,resource.submitted_by,topic_id) AS 'follows'*/

            /*,CASE
                WHEN follow.user_id IS NULL THEN 0
                ELSE 1 
            END AS 'follows'*/

            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE resource.submitted_by 
            END AS submitted_by
            ,CASE
                 WHEN resource.submitted_by = _user_id THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 
            END AS 'submitted_by_me'
            ,resource.resource_id
            ,'' AS 'likeCls'
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.date_added IS NULL THEN ''
                ELSE  DATE_FORMAT(resource.date_added, '%a, %d %b, %Y %H:%i:%S') 
                END AS 'date_added'
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN null
                ELSE user.thumbnail_image 
                END AS user_thumb
            ,CASE
                WHEN resource.isAnonymous = 1 THEN 'Anonymous'
                ELSE concat(user.first_name,' ', user.last_name)  
                END AS 'full_name'             
            ,20 AS probability 
            ,0 AS likesCount
            ,0 AS sharesCount
        FROM
            resource
            INNER JOIN topic_ids ON topic_ids.topic_id = resource.topic_id
            LEFT JOIN user_rating ON user_rating.resource_id = resource.resource_id AND user_rating.user_id = _user_id
            INNER JOIN topic ON topic.topic_id = resource.topic_id
            INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = resource.submitted_by
            /*LEFT JOIN follow ON follow.user_id = _user_id AND (follow.followee_user_id = resource.submitted_by AND follow.topic_id = topic_id)*/
        WHERE
            (user_rating.rating IS NULL) OR NOT (user_rating.rating = -2 OR user_rating.rating = -1 OR user_rating.rating = 2)
        ORDER BY 
            resource.date_added DESC
        LIMIT 
           offset, row_count;


    END IF;

    DROP TABLE topic_ids;        

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: As your procedure does nothing special like using cursors or something like that, it comes down to query optimizing. Run the `select` queries, that insert data and put the keyword  `explain` in front of it. Post the result and the table structures. Oh, and don't use variable/parameter names that can be confused with column or table names.

Comment: Hi tombom, I just did what u said. Its very complicated because from the all above queries, only the second insert query (INSERT INTO topic_ids
        (SELECT topic_children.topic_id FROM topic_children WHERE topic_children.parent_id = topic_id);) took 6 seconds. Others took less than 1s

Comment: Edit you question with the results of EXPLAIN for that query

Answer (score 0):

Check the indexes on the query that is running slowly.  Specifically, look for indexes on the columns used in your WHERE clauses, as well as indexes on your Foreign Keys used in your JOINS.  By default MySQL should index the Foreign Keys automatically (on InnoDB), but if those indexes are missing you might be doing a table scan on your JOIN, which would cause slower performance.